# qgis ver 2.0 vector layers not visible over raster

Tags: qgis-2

This seems like a simple thing, but I cannot get it to work in 2.01. I've done it extensively in 1.8.
I have vector line layers and raster layers. I put the vector line layer in order "above" or on top of the raster, but the lines do not display. If I turn off the raster, the line vector layer appears within the raster area. Lines outside of the raster boundary are always seen with the raster layer on. I've tried changing the order of the layers and nothing happens.

If I make the raster layer transparent I can see the vector lines. Either I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to right click in the TOC, getting the context dialog:

[image: Right click TOC]

Have you also tried using the Layer Order tab:

[image: Layer order tab]

If you do not have the Layer Order tab visible, just right click in the gray toolbar button area and pick Layer order:

[image: Customize]